# AWS EC2 Server Connection from Windows Network Error: Connection timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty, connection-timeout

I have created new EC2 instance set HTTP, HTTPS, SSH anywahere, get Pair, pem file, and tried to connect from window machine using putty.

Putty giving error:

> Network Error:  Network Error: Connection timeout error

I have tried same procedure from same laptop, same network, same firewall on different AWS account working fine.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

In security gruop I allowed SSH TCP 22 in inbound rule.

Comment: You can also try RDP without putty to ensure you can access the instance on your system successfully.

Comment: I tried RDP from Windows as well but still having same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot the connection, see: [Error connecting to your instance: Connection timed out](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout)

Overview:

- Check security groups
- Check route table
- Check Network ACL
- Check corporate network
- Check CPU load

Answer (score 0):

A timeout error normally indicates that your computer is unable to reach the target computer (as opposed to the target computer rejecting the connection).

Things to check:

- The EC2 instance should be running **Linux**
- The **security group** on the instance should be permitting inbound access on port 22 either from your IP address, or all IP addresses- The EC2 instance should be in a **public subnet** (defined as a subnet with a routing table entry pointing to an Internet Gateway)
- The Network Access Control Lists (**ACLs**) are preferably unchanged
- Your (corporate) network **permits SSH access** to the AWS network range

Given that you are able to connect to "a different AWS Account", it sounds like your laptop and local network configurations are find. It would have something to do with the instance, security group or VPC configuration.

Comment: Tried this one also. but no positive result

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried allowing connections on port 22?

- Go to your EC2 Instance and click on it so the radio button turns
  blue. Scroll down to the bottom and check for Security Groups.
- Click on View Inbound Rules and see if Port 22 is enabled. If not
  click on the link directly above *View Inbound Rules*. Screenshot below:

[image: Security Groups]

You will see the tabs as shown in the screenshot below: 
[image]

- Click on Edit then Add Rule Button.
- Enter the values as shown in the screenshot below:
- Click on Save then try connecting to your instance again.

[image]

- If that does not work, once you go to your EC2 instance, there is a Connect button. Click on that and see a list of possible warnings why you might be unable to connect to your instance. 
  [image]

Comment: I. Inbound rule 22 SSH on tcp allowed. Still have same issue

Answer (score 0):

Check your security group rules. You need a security group rule that allows inbound traffic from your public IPv4 address on the proper port.

- Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
- In the navigation pane, choose Instances, and then select your instance.
- In the Description tab at the bottom of the console page, next to Security groups, select view inbound rules to display the list of rules that are in effect for the selected instance.
- For Linux instances: When you select view inbound rules, a window will appear that displays the port(s) to which traffic is allowed. Verify that there is a rule that allows traffic from your computer to port 22 (SSH).
- For Windows instances: When you select view inbound rules, a window will appear that displays the port(s) to which traffic is allowed. Verify that there is a rule that allows traffic from your computer to port 3389 (RDP).